# queryPurchases() method doesn't show that android.test.purchased is owned

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I want to add a simple non-consumed product in my application. Following this
[billing_library_overview](http://%20https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview) and this [billing_testing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing) instructions, I decided to start with reserved product ID `android.test.purchased`. I got "Payment successful" message, but it looks like `queryPurchases()` method returns purchases list with `android.test.purchased` only one time when I call it in `onResume()` method. Everytime I call `queryPurchases()` after, I got purchasesResult.getPurchasesList() is equal to null.

Here is a valuable part of code:

```
public class MySettings extends PreferenceActivity
        implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, PurchasesUpdatedListener {

    private BillingClient mBillingClient;
    private Boolean bought = false;
    private String product_id = "android.test.purchased";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(this).build();
        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
        if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
                    skuList.add("android.test.purchased");      //I know it is not necessary
                    SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
                    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
                    mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                            new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                                        if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK
                                                && skuDetailsList != null) {
                                            for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                            });
                }   
            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            }
        });

        checkPurchase();
        createPreferenceScreen();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        checkPurchase();
        createPreferenceScreen();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
        if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
        }
        else {
        }
    }

    private void checkPurchase(){
        Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        if (purchasesResult.getPurchasesList() != null) {
            for (Purchase purchase : purchasesResult.getPurchasesList()){
                if (product_id.equals(purchase.getSku())) {
                    bought = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

In my `createPreferenceScreen()` method I check if `Boolean bought` is true or false. How can I restore that `android.test.purchased` was purchased already without using my own backend server?

**EDIT:** I didn't understand it, but it started to work when I moved my in-app-billing logic to main activity.